# Can't start automated test-case in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, appium-android, appium-desktop

I'm new in automated testing. So Unfortunately, can't run my automated test-case in RF-Ride.
System report is:
 - No application is open;
 - Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No application is open;
 - An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: You must include a platformName capability.

Can anyone help me with that trouble? I thouth, that it easy as written in RF description, wtf guys? I'm very nervous.

Here is my appium log:

- > [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"PlatformVersion":"8.0.0","deviceName":"f4506817","PlatformName":"Android","appActivity":"kg.megacom.megapay.MainActivity","appPackage":"kg.megacom.megapay"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"appium:deviceName":"f4506817","appium:appActivity":"kg.megacom.megapay.MainActivity","appium:appPackage":"kg.megacom.megapay","appium:PlatformName":"Android","appium:PlatformVersion":"8.0.0"}]}]
  >   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1561111676633 (16:07:56 GMT+0600 (Центральная Азия (зима)))
  >   [Appium] Could not parse W3C capabilities: The capabilities ["PlatformName"] are standard capabilities and should not have the "appium:" prefix
  >   [Appium] Trying to fix W3C capabilities by merging them with JSONWP caps
  >   [BaseDriver] The capabilities ["deviceName","appActivity","appPackage","PlatformVersion"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix
  >   [Appium] Could not parse fixed W3C capabilities: 'platformName' can't be blank. Falling back to JSONWP protocol
  >   [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1561111676644 (16:07:56 GMT+0600 (Центральная Азия (зима)))
  >   [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: You must include a platformName capability
  >   [MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.getDriverAndVersionForCaps (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:202:13)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.getDriverAndVersionForCaps [as createSession] (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:309:66)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\driver.js:319:19)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:471:26)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at executeCommand (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:352:34)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at asyncHandler (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:489:15)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at next (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at Route.dispatch (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
  >   [MJSONWP]     at Function.process_params (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at next (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at logger (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\morgan\index.js:144:5)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at trim_prefix (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
  >   [MJSONWP]     at Function.process_params (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at next (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
  >   [MJSONWP]     at invokeCallback (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at done (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:\Users\skozhobekov\AppData\Local\Programs\appium-desktop\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1090:12)
  >   [MJSONWP]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  >   [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 138 ms - 179
  >   [HTTP] ``

Comment: What version of Appium are you using before v1.6.13 platformName was case sensitive

Comment: i'm using the last version 1.13

Comment: Try renaming PlatformName to platformName